# How to separate modules in Django enterprise application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm going to create a large scale web application using Django.
It has 2 main parts website and API. also in API I have different modules(controller) like user, event and some other layers things like security, utility ...
I'm looking for an enterprise architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Use django to create a website and then expose whatever you want with django-tastypie as an API: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie

Comment: It should work well enough as well. Anyway I would firstly concentrate on a application database structure. If you start with well organized DB structure you will be able to scale you project easily by exposing things through your website or to some API.